# How to draw five rectangles in a bitmap and save it

Tags: c#

I want to draw five rectangles of different colors yet equal width and height with a 5px spacing between them, a 5px top and bottom margin too, in a bitmap in my resources folder and save the bitmap to Desktop.

When I run this code it only draws one Rectangle :

```
Bitmap palette = new Bitmap(Resources.palette);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(palette);

SolidBrush p1 = new SolidBrush(color1.BackColor);
SolidBrush p2 = new SolidBrush(color2.BackColor);
SolidBrush p3 = new SolidBrush(color3.BackColor);
SolidBrush p4 = new SolidBrush(color4.BackColor);
SolidBrush p5 = new SolidBrush(color5.BackColor);

var pal1 = new Rectangle(5, 5, 30, 90);
g.FillRectangle(p1, pal1);
var pal2 = new Rectangle(65, 40, 60, 90);
g.FillRectangle(p2, pal1);
var pal3 = new Rectangle(65, 35, 90, 90);
g.FillRectangle(p3, pal1);
var pal4 = new Rectangle(95, 50, 120, 90);
g.FillRectangle(p4, pal1);
var pal5 = new Rectangle(195, 5, 150, 95);
g.FillRectangle(p4, pal1);

palette.Save(@"C:\Users\Paapi\Desktop\"+DateTime.Now.Second+".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

MessageBox.Show("Completed");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Notice all your fill rectangles are referencing pal1, this is your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are drawing all them with the same rectangle, `pal1` :

```
var pal1 = new Rectangle(5, 5, 30, 90);
g.FillRectangle(p1, pal1);
var pal2 = new Rectangle(65, 40, 60, 90);
g.FillRectangle(p2, pal2);
var pal3 = new Rectangle(65, 35, 90, 90);
g.FillRectangle(p3, pal3);
var pal4 = new Rectangle(95, 50, 120, 90);
g.FillRectangle(p4, pal4);
var pal5 = new Rectangle(195, 5, 150, 95);
g.FillRectangle(p4, pal5);
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it all now. All the rectangles are drawing correctly now.